# Script to copy files depending on the windows version

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, gpo

(1st time poster.)
 I'm new to coding somewhat and have something I need to script up to place in a GPO. I have shortcuts I want to save to the taskbar. (%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar*.*) The problem is we have both windows 7 and 10 in our domain. All the shortcuts work execpt windows explorer. How do I create a script to where it looks at the windows version and applies the shortcut accordingly? Basically something like:

```
If version Windows 10 > Copy items in windows 10 shortcuts
or else
If version Windows 7 > Copy items in windows 7 shortcuts
```

Thanks in advance!

Windows 7 Bat File:

```
 del "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.*" /q
xcopy "\\servername\path\GPOScripts\Shortcuts\Windows 7\*.*" /e /v /y "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" /s /i
regedit.exe /s \\servername\path\GPOScripts\Windows10Settings\PinnedItems.reg
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer /v EnableAutoTray /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Windows 10:

```
del "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.*" /q
xcopy "\\servername\path\GPOScripts\Shortcuts\Windows 10\*.*" /e /v /y "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" /s /i
regedit.exe /s \\servername\path\GPOScripts\Windows10Settings\PinnedItems.reg
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu /v {20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D} /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer /v EnableAutoTray /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

Update:

I decided to go the powershell route and do to the following: (It works)

```
SVersion = (get-itemproperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ProductName).ProductName
if($OSVersion -eq "Windows 10 Pro")
{
Remove-Item "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.*"
Copy-item "\\server\Shortcuts\Windows 10\*.*" -Destination "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" -Recurse
}
ElseIf($OSVersion -eq "Windows 7 Pro")
{
Remove-Item "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.*"
Copy-item "\\server\Shortcuts\Windows 7\*.*" -Destination "%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar" -Recurse
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It sounds to me like the real question here is just "how can I tell the Windows version in a `bat` script", and the rest of the question is just implementation details, right?  (Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Comment: Thanks Max! I have no idea on where to start with that. It seems like vbs script might have to chime in. I only mess around mostly in the registry....

I would assume that it would be something similar to this?: 

@echo off
SET MCS_ENDPOINT=Sophos\Management Communications System\Endpoint\McsClient.exe
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" GOTO X86_PROG
IF NOT EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\%MCS_ENDPOINT%" GOTO INSTALL
exit /b 0

:X86_PROG
IF NOT EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\%MCS_ENDPOINT%" GOTO INSTALL
exit /b 0

:INSTALL
pushd \\server\path
Setup.exe --quiet
Popd